# Effectively (in terms of performance) store and use set values in MySQL

Tags: sql, performance, mysql

I need to store set value in MySQL column. I completely like the build-in [`SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html) type, but it seems that `FIND_IN_SET()` function requires table scan which is bad.

It seems that `SET` uses binary values under the hood. If I use binary value to represent a set, for example for a set of four elements it could be something like this:

0100
0101
0110
etc

How I can store it (which type), how to query and take advantage of indexes?

P.S. I indeed need a solution without separate linking table, something similar to SET.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You've got a clear reason for this "I need", don't you?

Comment: I want to store statuses for my objects, each object can have multiple statuses. More normalized solution is to have separate linking table for 'many-to-many' relations, but I'd like to have it more simply on SQL side to be able to query table of objects directly, without joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use BIT field type and use [Bit functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html) for quering, however you will need hardcode somewhere yours set values in binary form. Other disadvantage that you can have only 64 possible values.

Comment: Hadcoding values is not a problem. 

But if I'd like to select records where first and second bit are set to 1 it seems the full table scan is needed anyway?

Comment: @artvolk, Index will be used if you create index for your field

Comment: Your solution seems to be exactly what I need, but it seems indexes are not used if I put bitwise functions in WHERE. More details in separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560514/mysql-doesnt-use-indexes-when-query-over-bit-field-using-bitwise-functions